# can not upload Android App Bundle on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I tried to upload an Android App Bundle (for an existing app) on the Google Play. I have done the google signing part, And it says Releases signed by Google Play. Buy after i upload my aab file to the release, it said that "you uploaded a file that is not a well-formed zip archive". Anyone knows why this problem occur, and how i can fix it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to delete the release and make new one and don't forget to increase the bundle version code

Comment: Did anything worked? I have the same issue.

Comment: i have fixed this problem. make sure your bundle version is correct and increased.

Answer (score 1):

My problem with this one was very peculiar.

Scenario was next: I needed to upload aab file, which needed to be downloaded from our Jenkins server. What was happening is that for some reason it wasn't downloading the full aab file, but a reduced amount of data. In the download folder I had some previous versions of those files, so I assume some sort of optimization took place in the background due to the nature of those archive files.  For example Jenkins showed 30MB, and my downloads were 15MB, or even less if I had more aab files in that folder. Even deletion of them didn't work.

What worked eventually was deleting those files from Trash (I'm using Mac), and attempting download after that.